# new solution not loading some projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am using `TFS 2012` (online version).

**Situation**:
I made a solution that had multiple projects inside of it.  I added it to `TFS` via the `Visual Studio` interface ("Add solution to Source Control").  That all worked fine.

Later I decided on a radical redesign of the code.  I was not sure if I wanted it to go beyond the concept so I kept it local.

Now it is something I want to use.  The new version has two projects that have the same name space as two projects in the old solution.  When I add this solution to TFS the two projects that share a name with a project in another solution do not get added to the new source control "folder" (for lack of a better name).

```
OLD Solution:
myapp.webstuff
myapp.model
myapp.dal
myapp.interface

NEW solution:
myapp.mobilestuff
myapp.model   <-- not added to source control
myapp.dal     <-- not added to source control
myapp.webservices 

TFS
Folder: BuildScripts
Folder: OldSolution
Folder: NewSolution
```

I think it has something to with the name of the two projects being the same.  It must view them as the same and not load them to the source control.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Although the projects themselve would not be added to the source control library, adding files in the project to the library would add the project.
So just add the files in the project and the project will come along.